# yii defaultcontroller change?

Tags: php, yii

I have changed my `defaultController` to my desired `contoller` and changed `action` in `login` to `array(mycontroller/action)`.

When whenever i am just paste my project url into address bar and enter it shows the previous `contoller` that is `SiteController` (that i have removed).
but on clicking `login` tab it woks fine

```
'defaultController'=>'user',// i defined it user earliar it was site
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution. I have define `loginUrl` in `yii` `config` `main.php` to my desired `url`

```
 'loginUrl' => '/project_upload/index.php/user/login'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change default controller than you need to use below code in add the configuration in the config main.php:

```
return array(
    'name' => 'Web Application',
    'defaultController' => 'home', 
    ......
);
```